# PayPal Thank You Page by form variable

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've created a payment button in Paypal, and I'd like to pass a user's input as a variable to the thank you page. (`domain.com/thank-you?uid=$ID`).

So I've added a `<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="return" value="domain.com/thank-you?" id="my-id">` according to the [doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/)

and I've added an OnClick event to the submit button, `submitElement.addEventListener("click", clickFunc, false);`

And it is working nicely (tested it out with `alert` & then implemnted the `uid=$ID` addition to the hidden `return` value). But PayPal does nothing with my return value. PayPal simply leaves the clients on their `Successfully Paid` Page.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using HTML forms to redirect to PayPal, a return may never happen. Depending on the user's locale and funding method, PayPal may need to show them a receipt, and click a link to return. Or their browser may crash. If you require a return to happen, this is the wrong integration method.

The best integration method to receive a successful notification of completed payments is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client, either that client-side-only version or the pattern that communicates with a server.

To use the server version, create two routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

---

Either way, on successful capture you can display a thank you message in any way you wish.  Including a redirect if you are feeling old-fashioned.

Comment: Thanks, it appears that this new PayPal Smart Button takes a `return-url` value in it's `createOrder` function. Thanks!
And my thank you page is generating a custom PDF & I'm trying to keep the site 100% static so... That's why I'm using such a weird implementation. Thanks again!

Comment: A returnURL is not used with smart buttons.

Comment: It is.. Works for me..... and I am using a Smart Button.